# Warm/Hot Water Sediment Housing and filters

Tags: water-filtration

I need a sediment filter after the water heater. There is a clear one made of
Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene. I read in wiki this can get up to 80 degree Celsius.

[image]

But I learnt there are separate sediment housing for warm/hot water.

[image]

Its made of glass-reinforced nylon base.

I like the clear one so I can see how dirty the filter is. Can you tell how dirty it is by merely looking? This is the advantage of the clear housing.

If I'd get the red one. I can't see the filters.

What chemicals could be release by either? I guess they both don't have BPA. Since both can handle 80 degree celsius. What is the advantage of the red one?

Comment: You don't need to see the filter. It's far more effective to have a pressure gauge on either side of the fiter, and to look at them while water is passing through the filter to observe the pressure drop, which is diagnostic of the extent to which the filter is actually clogged.